# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Politics Stack Exchange](http://politics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: I dont know about anyone else but I was happy to notice that the trend seems to be better questions and answers.  Lets hope it continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is the US Attorney General expected to defend policies his party opposes in the Supreme Court?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/is-the-us-attorney-general-expected-to-defend-policies-his-party-opposes-in-the)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [If a US Supreme Court justice dies between voting and releasing ruling, does their vote count?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/if-a-us-supreme-court-justice-dies-between-voting-and-releasing-ruling-does-the)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does the Hobby Lobby case apply to all corporations and all birth control?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3439/does-the-hobby-lobby-case-apply-to-all-corporations-and-all-birth-control)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Are Running Mates Constitutional (US President/VP)](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/are-running-mates-constitutional-us-president-vp)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Which US laws apply on a Native American/ Indian Reservation?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/which-us-laws-apply-on-a-native-american-indian-reservation)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why haven't any Governments banned cigarette sales when it has been proven that it's harmful?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/why-havent-any-governments-banned-cigarette-sales-when-it-has-been-proven-that)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [In Australia, what does the term "Big polluters" mean?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/in-australia-what-does-the-term-big-polluters-mean)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Is ban on Social Interaction with opposite sex a Human Rights Violation?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3371/is-ban-on-social-interaction-with-opposite-sex-a-human-rights-violation)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [How was arranging the trade of POW Sgt. Bowe Bergdahl for five detainees possible without “negotiating with terrorists”?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3366/how-was-arranging-the-trade-of-pow-sgt-bowe-bergdahl-for-five-detainees-possibl)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Does banning of anti-democratic parties violate principles of democracy?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3347/does-banning-of-anti-democratic-parties-violate-principles-of-democracy)

**Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

Comment: I will admit I am confused by the apparent problems people have with:Does banning of anti-democratic parties violate principles of democracy?  What is it i am missing?

Comment: @Chad, my 2 cents: the Q did not indicate any substantial own research. It is a bit vague since there are many levels of banning and oppression. The Q also welcomes opinionated answers since not many parties, incl. extreme ones, openly nominate themselves "anti-democratic". None of the answers cite credible references; they only confirm OP's point of duality between "own freedom" versus "freedom for the others". Personally, it did not teach me of anything new.